# What is the relationship between coefficient of discharge, Cd and the viscosity of the fluid flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

Will an orifice’s coefficient of discharge depend on the viscosity of the fluid being used to measure it?

Is Cd a geometric property or will it change for different fluids of different viscosity?

Are there any empirical relations relating the two?